# Django PositiveBigIntegerField

Tags: python, django, django-model-field

So, im trying to work on my apps and I have PositiveBigIntegerField's in some of my models. I thought for sure it was already included with Django but now i'm starting to think otherwise. Whenever I run my server, im getting an error stating that `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'PositiveBigIntegerField'` Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: What version of Django do you use? This was new in Django-3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I'm trying to work on my apps and I have PositiveBigIntegerField's in some of my models. I thought for sure it was already included with Django but now I'm starting to think otherwise.

**It is**, but only since [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1). Indeed, [the documentation of the **`PostiveBigIntegerField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#positivebigintegerfield) specifies that this was introduced then.

You can however easily implement this yourself, as specified in the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e59d1ff5627cf9cc551e160d65858a37693de4ed/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2224-L2236):

> ```
> class PositiveBigIntegerField(PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin, BigIntegerField):
>     description = _("Positive big integer")
>
>     def get_internal_type(self):
>         return "PositiveBigIntegerField"
>
>     def formfield(self, **kwargs):
>         return super().formfield(
>             **{
>                 "min_value": 0,
>                 **kwargs,
>             }
>         )
> ```

Where you thus import `PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin` and `BigIntegerField` from the `django.db.models.fields` module.